# How can we maintain the location trail of location updated by Geofire android?

Tags: android, firebase, geofire

I have a Geofire app which is cotinously updating( not appending) the location of device on location change over firebase database. Now i want to store all the location updates so that i can see the path followed by app.

Is there any direct function available in geofire android sdk to achieve the same.

I can accomplish it by maintaining different node and appnending everytime i see location change.

But i want an inbuild function which is doing the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to Geofire to track an object over time.

I'd indeed keep that information in a separate node in the database:

```
Devices
    <device_id>
        Geodata
            <timestamp or push id>
                g: ...
```

With the above structure, you can still Geoquery the historic locations of each individual device.

Alternatively (if you also want to fire Geoqueries on the previous locations across all devices) you could generate separate unique keys for each position of the device:

```
Geodata
    <device_id>_<timestamp_of_data>
        g: ...
```